# Django: Order by the amount of comments

Tags: django, django-filter

I want to order my objects by the amount of comments they have. This is how my models look

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class Comment(models.Models):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    ...
```

And this is how I currently try to `order_by` the amount of comments:

```
...
results = Post.objects.all()
results = results.order_by('-post__comment')
...
return render(request, 'post.html', {'posts': results})
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following error in my template,

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'post' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, ..
```

when I try to

```
{% for post in posts %}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [annotate the queryset and order by the annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by).

```
from django.db.models import Count

posts = Post.objects.annotate(num_comments=Count('comment')).order_by('-num_comments')
```

Comment: Yes you both were right! Man there are so many awesome things in django I don't know yet :D

Comment: I double checked the field name to use. If you have specified a related_name for the foreign key, then use the related name. If you have not specified a related_name, then use `comment`, not `comment_set` in the annotation.

Comment: No I didn't use `related_name`. Another awesome thing I can use that I didn't know about yet! :D